# Update JSX content in React Js with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a Memory Game with React Js, but I can't update my game board when I shuffle my cards. This is the project:

1. I created a array with cards names like this:

```
export default ["Earth","Jupiter","Mars","Mercury","Moon"...
```

2. I created a function to update and shuffle this array using useState:

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState(CardData.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));

function ResetBoard() {
    setBoard(board.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));
    console.log(board);
}
```

3. Call ResetBoard() in my button:

```
<button className="retry-btn" onClick={ResetBoard}>
```

4. Render board in my JSX code:

```
<div className="card-section">
    {board.map((Card) => (
       <div className="card" key={Card}>
           <img
            src={require(`../assets/cards/${Card}.png`)}
            alt="Cards"
            width="100px"
            height="100px"/>
       </div>
     ))}
</div>
```

But when I click in the Reset Button, my board state change (in console) but the front-end don't change.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to declare your useEffect in the html. If you check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html the useEffect is declared before the return statement.

Comment: Oh thanks, makes sense, I thought this too but when I write only {board.map(...)} also don't work. I'm starting to learn ReactJs, do you know how I fix or search this problem?

Comment: I'm kinda surprised that Jagratis answer does not work - can you share the code of the entire component? I might be able to spot what's wrong then :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `useEffect` in render.

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState(CardData.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));

function ResetBoard() {
    setBoard(CardData.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)); // use CardData.sort to reset the board state
}

.......

<div className="card-section">
    {board.map(Card => (
        <div className="card" key={Card}>
           <img
            src={require(`../assets/cards/${Card}.png`)}
            alt="Cards"
            width="100px"
            height="100px"/>
        </div>
     ))}
</div>
```

`console.log(board)` immediately after `setBoard` will not return updated state, because state updates are async in nature.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried this too, but nothing changes, this is a print screen for illustrate my situation: [Img Link](https://imgur.com/VmZ02Zh).
But thanks by the answer and help.

Comment: While resetting the board state, you need to use `CardData`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Good morning, I solved the problem refreshing the componente using useHistory from react-router-dom, I created a function for reload the component.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
const [board] = useState(CardData.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));

function shuffleBoard(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push("/game");
  }
```

It works for while.

Thanks for everyone what helped me.